# php array usage in javascript, jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Using JsonEncode I got a php array in Javascript. How I can get the modified array back to php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a JSON string to a PHP object:

```
$obj = json_decode($some_json);
echo $obj->field1; // where field1 is a known field
```

TO get a JSON string to an associative array:

```
$arr = json_decode($some_json, true);
echo $arr['field1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you need [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. You can easily convert array encoded in json-format to the php-array

Comment: That is, after you have submitted it to a php script via ajax or through a form submit.